# Grails 2.4.0 upgrade - env variables

Tags: grails, environment-variables

What am I doing wrong here? I'm moving to Grails 2.4.0 (Windows 7 enterprise) and am having troubles with my environment variables set up correctly. Here's my stuff....

GRAILS_HOME `C:\grails\grails-2.4.0`

JAVA_HOME `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51`

yet when I run-app from a cmd prompt I get this:

```
C:>echo %GRAILS_HOME% C:\grails\grails-2.3.7
```

and also...here is entire PATH variable

```
%GRAILS_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_32\bin;%System‌​Root%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%systemroot%\System32\Wind‌​owsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\SlikSvn\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\ActivIdentity\ActivClient\;C:\Program Files\ActivIdentity\ActivClient\
```

Given the above... when I do a run-app I get the following. What could be wrong and does it relate to my env variables?

```
C:\Users>grails run-app Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.vendor="Sun Microsystems Inc." Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:/grails/grails-2.3.7/lib/org. springframework/springloaded/jars/springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar Error occurred during initialization of VM agent library failed to init: instrument

C:\Users>
```

Comment: You're not setting GRAILS_HOME correctly. I'm not a Windows user, but [this link](https://kb.wisc.edu/cae/page.php?id=24500) looks promising.

Comment: I had configured and working correctly under Grails 2.3.7 with the C:\grails\grails-2.3.7 as my path.   The path C:\grails\grails-2.4.0 is correct; I double-checked it.  In fact I copied it directly from the folder window itself.

Comment: The path looks ok, but your echo command is returning the wrong value for GRAILS_HOME. It should return 2.4.0. If you set it from the command line, it only works for that session. Check the link in my first comment to make it permanent.

Comment: I deleted and recreated the GRAILS_HOME var with the correct path, but the cmd prompt still returns the error.  I'm sorry if I'm still missing something.

Comment: I may have figured out a work-around... it's possible that the app may have been trying to access C:\grails\current -- so I just copied the stuff from C:\grails\grails-2.4.0 into there.

Comment: You should consider using GVM for Cygwin or perhaps Posh-GVM. They are Groovy environment managers that make installing and switching between Groovy/Grails versions very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you need to restart your command line session to resolve/reflect the changes you mande to GRAILS_HOME.